# How to join 2 rows in one table by ID

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to do statisitics about namesakes (people with same name and different personal_identidy_code). I would like to join 2 or more rows into 1 row so i can contioune comparing data with CASE statements.

Lets say, i have a query output like that:

```
acitivityNR  acitivityName  Personal_identity_code    Name
111             test             00000000001          hello wor
111             test2            00000000002          hello wor
111             test2            00000000002          hello wor
222             asd              11111111111          my name
222             asd2             11111111112          my name
```

There can be more then 2 rows with same activityNR (activityName can be different). I have more then 1 activitys in my output. I need to compare, if in activityNr 111 has people with same name, but different personal identity code.
I have idea to join these rows into one, so i have output like that:

```
acitivityNR = aNR
acitivityName = aName
Personal_identity_code = code

aNR Aname Code         Name       Code2     Name2      Code3      Name3
111 test 00000000001 hello wor 00000000002 hello wor 00000000002 hello wor
222 asd  11111111111 my name   11111111112  my name
```

and from there i can use CASE statement to filter out outputs where code = code2 = code3

This is what i have, with some where sententences also, but thats not important right now.

```
select a.activityNR, a.activityName, p.prsonal_identity_code, p.name
from things t
inner join activitys a on t.id = a.things_id
inner join activitys_people ap on a.id = ap.activitys_id
inner join people p on ap.people_id = p.id
order by a.activityNR asc
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select a1.activityNR, a1.activityName, a1.prsonal_identity_code,
       a2.activityName, a2.prsonal_identity_code
from activitys a1
  inner join activitys a2 on a1.acitivityNR = a2.acitivityNR
where a1.prsonal_identity_code <> a2.prsonal_identity_code
```

This would give you results like the following:

```
aNR Aname Code         Name       Code2     Name2
111 test 00000000001 hello wor 00000000002 hello wor
111 test 00000000001 hello wor 00000000002 hello wor
222 asd  11111111111 my name   11111111112  my name
```